# UIAutomation API for testing IOS

Tags: ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Where can i download UIAutomation API for testing IOS (on JavaScript)?

Comment: This is probably the wrong place to ask that question.  If you have a question that pertains to actual code, feel free!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that UIAutomation APIs are downloadable. Most you can do is, write a script in .js and run it through intruments. Instruments intermadiatly complie that to produce automation. What exactly you want to do with that downloaded APIs and where you want to run it? If you just want a reference then you can get it on apple developer [site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html).